# Eclipse The import org.hibernate cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, hibernate

I'm quite new to Android SDK. I'm trying to use Hibernate/Criteria but it gives an error.

I have installed Hibernate following these steps.

```
Help -> Install New Software
Click on Add. Location: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/
Inside JBoss Web and Java EE Development folder, select Hibernate Tools
Click on Next
```

I can see that Hibernate has been installed in Eclipse but why the error keeps showing?

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
```

error

```
The import org.hibernate cannot be resolved
```

file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

import org.hibernate.Criteria; 


public class MyMapActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleMap googleMap; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        //set map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);      

        // Show the current location in Google Map        
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
    }
```

Comment: have u added hibernate jars to class path of project

Comment: mmm nope! How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Hibernate Jar to your project classpath or to your eclipse library list.

Also, by adding Help-> Install New Software you are adding Hibernate plugin for eclipse and not adding Hibernate lib to your eclipse project.

Here are some links for adding jars to eclipse project or classpath:

[How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Comment: Ok, so the classpath is /src but where can find the .jars?

Comment: Download your required version from net eg: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/

Comment: I have currently installed 4.2.1. Is it fine to download 3.* jars or do I have to download 4.2.1 jars?

Comment: If no specific requirement for version, download latest which is 4.2.1.

Comment: Thanks! I have done everything and now the error is gone but I got a new error `Cannot instantiate the type Criteria`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Would please paste your complete Java file?

Comment: Criteria is an interface so cant create instance directly. Visit for more details http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm

Comment: But I have seen it many Google Maps tutorials. eg:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679205/android-locationmanager-criteria

Comment: I finally found the solution. I'm not even suppose to use `Hibernate`. I'm suppose to use `android.Criteria`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepak Shingan! Appreciate it.

Comment: This is interesting,I'd  assumed that the plugin cannot work without those jars.

Answer (score 0):

Guys First go to add Your configure(buildpath) in jar.files;
and check the maven repository  to click access,liber,like that and  add path location of all then its clear
elseif ( u can clear this is in automatic bug fix suggestion in your eclipse when trace full error codes in eclipse )then go to fix setup and add jar

otherwise last way : to use to  solve this is easy way,Its Nothing but use your com.dao or anyname class as com.hibernate;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).